# AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap issue with keydown

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm using AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap() to load an external form with this code:

```
System.AppDomain appDomain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewAppDomain",  null, adSetup);

var assemblyLoaderType = typeof(AssemeblyLoader);
var assemblyLoader = (IAssemblyLoader)appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyLoaderType.Assembly.Location, assemblyLoaderType.FullName);

assemblyLoader.LoadForm(bytes, "Dll_Test.Form1", "");


public class AssemeblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject, IAssemblyLoader
{
    public void LoadForm(byte[] bytes, string nomeIstanza, string parametri)
    {
        var assembly = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(bytes);

        Type b = assembly.GetType(nomeIstanza);
        object c = Activator.CreateInstance(b);

        Form frm = (Form)c;
        frm.Show();
```

It works fine, the only issue is when I use keydown in the form: all keycode are caught, except ESC, ENTER button:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

    // All triggered except enter\esc button

    MsgBox(e.KeyCode)

End Sub
```

Can you help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: how are you binding the keydown event to textbox1? Just so we know

Comment: @jegtugado It's there in the code, the `Handles` clause on the handler declaration.

Comment: i have a dll with a form, where i bind TextBox1.KeyDown. Every keycode is catched fine, except esc \ enter keys

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the issue.  It appears that the form created in the secondary domain does not call the textbox's IsInputKey nor the ProcessDialogKey methods.  However, if you call `Form.ShowDialog` versus `Form.Show` the escape and enter keys are processed in the KeyDown event.

Comment: Thanks!...i tried with ShowDialog and it works...but in this way my request form remain blocked

Comment: So there's no solutions without using Form.ShowDialog ?